# TIFF File displaying as a negative

Tags: c#

I am storing TIFF formatted images in a sql table but when I retrieve and display in a WPF Control, some of them they are displaying as a negative. What can I use in the TIFF format structure to determine if it will display as a negative and what can I do to convert\display the image correctly?

Comment: Why are you storing huge binaries in an RDBMS table?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? How are you inserting/mutating data? **Exactly** what happens to a file on a user's desktop as it enters your database? (I swear.... if I hear another Base64 `data:` URI story...)

Comment: The sql data type i'm using is "Image". It works fine, but the original image that was converted from a PDF using Nuance Omnipage CSDK didn't check the palette before saving to the table. The original files are not available. Looking for a way to evaluate the tiff image once it's retrieved from the table to determine whether it's inverted and if so, correct it and then save back to table.

Comment: You can examine the TIFF tags metadata of the retrieved image to see if there is a specific tag that is causing it to display as negative. An imaging toolkit like LEADTOOLS can extract all the TIFF tags in an image using the [RasterCodecs.ReadTags](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/co/rastercodecs-readtags(string,int).html) method. Alternatively, the toolkit also has the [InvertedPageCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/po/invertedpagecommand.html) which can detect and correct for negative images. (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of this toolkit)